# How to type provided class properties in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Following is a Nest.Js custom decorator

```
import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PermissionPolicy } from '../permission.policy';

type ClassThatExtends<TClass = any> = new (...args) => TClass;

// Check if user has provided permission to access this route
export const Acl = <
  // this means expecting the class not an instance,
  TPolicyClass extends ClassThatExtends<PermissionPolicy>,
  TActions extends (keyof InstanceType<TPolicyClass>)[],
>(
  policyClass: TPolicyClass,
  actions: TActions,
) => {
  const policyInstance = new policyClass();

  const requiredPermissions = actions.reduce((acc, actionName) => {
    return [...acc, ...policyInstance[actionName]];
    // >> TS2536: Type 'keyof InstanceType ' cannot be used to index type 'PermissionPolicy'.
  }, [] as string[]);

  return SetMetadata('aclPermissions', requiredPermissions);
};
```

What is the problem here? how to solve this?

For now I'm suppressing the error like following but I've a feeling that this is not the correct way.

```
return [...acc, ...policyInstance[actionName as keyof PermissionPolicy]];
```

Expected usage

```
@Acl(AuthPolicy, ['update']) // 'update' is property of AuthPpolicy
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure why your code fails, however, the generics are a bit complex and when simplified, the problem gets solved.

I think part of the problem is that generic can *always* be specified explicitly, like

```
Acl<typeof AuthPolicy, ['base']>(...)
```

Which makes it harder for the compiler to ensure that those types can be paired up logically.

I wish I had a better answer for you about why this fails.

---

But, the thing is, you don't need be generic over the class constructor. you don't care what that constructor is, except for the fact that it constructs an instance that descends from `PermissionPolicy`.

You also don't need to be generic over `TActions` because you aren't doing anything with that type.

Which means that you can simplify this to:

```
export const Acl = <TPolicy extends PermissionPolicy>(
  policyClass: new () => TPolicy, // constructor should take zero args, since you aren't passing any
  actions: (keyof TPolicy)[],
) => {
  const policyInstance = new policyClass();

  const requiredPermissions = actions.reduce<string[]>((acc, actionName) => {
    [...acc, ...policyInstance[actionName]];
    // Type 'TPolicy[keyof TPolicy]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.(2488)
  }, []);

  return SetMetadata('aclPermissions', requiredPermissions);
};
```

This is at least, a different error. Here the error is basically saying that it can't guarantee that `policyInstance[actionName]` is an array. But you can check for that.

```
export const Acl = <TPolicy extends PermissionPolicy>(
  policyClass: new () => TPolicy,
  actions: (keyof TPolicy)[],
) => {
  const policyInstance = new policyClass();

  const requiredPermissions = actions.reduce<string[]>((acc, actionName) => {
    const value = policyInstance[actionName]

    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      return [...acc, ...value];
    } else {
      // Or maybe throw?
      return acc
    }
  }, []);

  return SetMetadata('aclPermissions', requiredPermissions);
};
```

See [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#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)

---

You could also use a utility type to find just the keys that have a type of `string[]` with something like:

```
type StringArrayKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]:
    T[K] extends string[] ? K : never
}[keyof T]

export const Acl = <TPolicy extends PermissionPolicy>(
  policyClass: new () => TPolicy,
  actions: StringArrayKeys<TPolicy>[],
) => { /* ... */ }
```

And now the key *must* correspond to a string array to be valid.

You still have to do the runtime check though to make the type checker sure, though.

See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgZQKYwLLoIYBNszZwC+cAZlBCHAOQACAdqgM4wBWzA9AMZUgQMaAbgCwAKHEwAnmFQoYUYAwDmAQShRsUgNKopzADwAVAHxwAvInFw4AbW1wlcANZ6IZOEYC6ALms3Pey84VAAPGFQGXGY4VkUVW2CAfjgHHzgmADdUKHFiW1cpd08vcXFOTjgAYQALVG5nRw8AV2YcuBrsGLBKTOBcVFw4WSgQYGZmYAE4GAg4bG5uFhiYGvG4SmaI8TDIWDheBlY4VW4AGws4YwAFCDPgbikQ8MjouGucsYmphlv7x5MAAp-JB-lIqmcusx0kwAO5wQEASgsZiMfweUgANP4FjAftD5PE1BotLp9Dc7hiTIlsWJkeYzAh-IdjqCMQBJI6EBhLS5w4aUx4QqFI0QSMQ2FnwKCoACOzWAMtwH1G40mAhillx+IAdErmksDHElMpEkDAQtuJj5tw8QIAHLYECoemM-ySjXwTLYM7NOSWNmPTmsbA81C2bUOp2oUrigJNBHqTRSHXjJNaQHe30u5FMiXxjboZpQBh2HXly3W8s6rN+rxi+OkVBnNpWfPxipwADyUDgIC0ACM5KtKLCku6AjKYMXS5aJ8R-MRrYlEWL-FOZyh0FhCPhCICaAsziqvuqjjRrTL5YrBie1fjV3k12JzlD3p97wJ0Y9EHAB11-TsQ8aGCBcX0hCYTi2GpvyeMIIiiGI72+L9BSeJBmjAPdANsGgBxAoQ4AgVZ2ksBQ-RIMpxVOM5AVUaDYOXGhMOwkDkU7WFoGcZhxBouiGLQpjiLqKA2LgTsckoXsumeWRbUGIA)

---

Sometimes a lot of weird typescript issues can be solved by simplifying your types. This means that the type checker has to jumps through fewer hoops to match things up.